# byte array to PDF in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, byte, data-conversion

I need to do something in Python 2.7 that I'm able to to in Python 3.

This code works in Python 3 to write an array to PDF.

```
PDFbyteArray = [37, 80, 68, 70...]

with open('NewPDFfile.pdf', 'wb') as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(bytes(PDFbyteArray))
```

When I try to do the same thing in python 2 it doesn't convert the array to bytes. From what I have read online the `bytes()` function is a python 3 thing. So my question is how do I achieve the same result in python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.6+, to convert a list of integers to what you need (an array of bytes), use the built-in [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) class:

```
PDFbyteArray = [37, 80, 68, 70]

with open('NewPDFfile.pdf', 'wb') as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(bytearray(PDFbyteArray))

print('fini')
```